# Create two separate Woocommerce registration forms on separate pages for separate user roles?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

Can anyone help guide me the process of creating two separate woocommerce registration form pages for two different user roles?

I have installed the woocommerce wholesale prices plugin to enable me to create wholesale listings in the store along with the wholesale user role

My client has now asked to create two separate pages with a registration form for retail customers and a registration page for wholesale customers.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `register_form` hook to do that

```
add_action('register_form','add_different_field');

function add_different_field(){
    if (isset($_GET['role'])){
        if($_GET['role'] == 'wholesaler'){
        echo '<input id="user_email" type="hidden" tabindex="20" size="25" value="'.$_GET['role'].'" name="role"/>';
 // or more fields
       }else{
         // Add other user fields
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alice, thank you very much for your reply, I still cannot seem to get this working.... how and where would you add the action and the hook? And how would I implement this for two separate pages, for the two separate roles: 'wholesale customer' and also 'customer'? any additional help would be amazing.

Comment: first add this code to your theme's functions.php, use same url of registration form but in the request url pass -  role=wholesale